# Variadic lambda vs variadic template function : stricly equivalent?

Tags: c++

Consider this code snippet

```
#include <chrono>
auto wrapAndCallLambda = 
[] (auto fn, auto &&... params)
{
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto result = fn(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    const auto elapsed = end - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << "s";
    return result;
};


template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
auto wrapAndCall(Fn fn, Args &&... params)
 {
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto result = fn(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    const auto elapsed = end - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << "s";
    return result;
 }
```

Is it stricly  equivalent ?  Is there any consideration to have in mind (not related to opinion and style)  guiding which one to choose ?
Code bloating ?
Performances ?
Compile time if used extensively ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wrapAndCallLambda` is an actual object, whereas `wrapAndCall` is a template.

This means that you can pass `wrapAndCallLambda` directly to other functions, and you have to either explicitly pass `&wrapAndCall<fn_type, arg1, arg2, ...>`, or wrap it into another lambda which forwards its arguments.

This also means that you cannot overload or specialize `wrapAndCallLambda`, but you can easily write another overload for `wrapAndCall`.

You also can never find `wrapAndCallLambda` via ADL. Which may be a feature you want.

Comment: w.r.t. "explicitly pass" - you're not actually passing the lambda object in that case, but instead a pointer-to-function that the (instantiated) method got converted to, right? And if so does that mean it only works for captureless-lambdas?